# Cross Domain Call in Javascript without JQuery

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I am using JQuery for X-Domain call.

I need to save network costs for mobile user and want to remove Jquery.

My current J-Query powered cross domain call is as follows:

```
  var data_from_ajax;
  $.get('MyURLgoeshere', function(data) {
  data_from_ajax = data;
  //and other things go there
  }
```

My endpoint URL is CORS-enabled.

How do I go convert the above without JQuery? Is there a function for this?

Comment: use `XMLHttpRequest` or the newer `fetch` ... actually, don't use fetch, IOS Safari (and desktop safari and IE, not important for mobile user) don't support it

Comment: I may have to look into XMLHttpRequest as Fetch doesn't work on all browsers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

```
function pinglistener () {
}

var xdomaincallfunction =  function(){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener("load", pinglistener);
request.open("GET", "MYURLGOESHERE");
request.send();
}
```